# Can you edit Apple ProRes in iMovie '11?

Tags: imovie, prores

I have an older Mac Pro, and I am not able to run Final Cut Pro X because of graphics card limitations.  However, because I have it installed, it seems like the codecs are present that are required for iMovie.

We are capturing video on a Hyperdeck Studio Pro 2 and using the Apple ProRes encoding.

Currently I can do an import, and iMovie will import the file. However, this takes so long that I can only assume it is converting the ProRes file into something else, and it's very disruptive to the workflow.

Besides the massive wait time to import the files, iMovie seems fine for our editing process, which involves trimming the video, adding an intro slide at the beginning, and exporting to Vimeo.

Is there some way in iMovie to edit the ProRes file directly so that I can skip the import step?  I feel like I should just be able to open it in iMovie, and start editing right away.